# Can I mutate state passed to setState function?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I know I should not mutate state directly in React, but how about situation when I use function:

```
onSocialClick = e => {
    const id = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        prevState[id] = !(prevState[id]);
        return prevState;
    });
};
```

**Is it a mistake to modify passed object?**

**EDIT:**

It turns out that most of us were wrong here. React [docs state it clearly](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) now:

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props

Thanks to @Tomáš Hübelbauer for pointing it out in the comment.

Comment: It isn't a mistake :) Not modify state directly means you should use `setState`, not `this.state =...`. If you do - everything is ok, whatever you use as incoming parameter.

Comment: @Tomasz I asked a follow up question because I had my doubts about your code snippet. You may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47339643/2715716

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer thanks! I've made an edit.

Comment: I tried to find the exact statement in the docs, but looks like they renamed the variable- `prevState` is now just `state`

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way would be to refer directly to the property you want do edit:

```
doIt = () => this.setState(({ [id]: prevValue }) => ({
  [id]: !prevValue,
}));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this if `[id]` is not a direct child of `state`, but one level down? In my case I have an array of `[id]`s, and all other Q/As and articles suggest making copies but I find your solution clearer.

Comment: @Al.G. you will have probably to use `find` to get the right index to access the right array element

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is not wrong. Its perfectly okk to modify the argument and then return it. However setState with prevState argument is used when you modify the state based on the value of the prevState and it prefectly fits your scenario and a more cleaner way to handle it would be

```
onSocialClick = e => {
    const id = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return {[id] : !(prevState[id])};
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> No, you should not mutate the prevState in updater function of setState.
>
> Updater function has to be a pure function

> The updater function is called twice. See this [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856) 
>   
> Check the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setstate-lpyfl) and open the console of the codesandbox to see it in action.

Answer (score -1):

It is highly discouraged to mutate the state directly. Also, you are mutating the previous state and then returnning it which doesnt make much sense. If all you want is to toggle the state at `state[id]` then fix your code to be more like:

```
onSocialClick = e => {
    const id = e.target.value;
    this.setState({this.state[id]: !this.state[id});
};
```

Comment: this is discouraged, you should use the functional way as used by OP (but maybe using directly the interested props.