# Is it okay to treat the prevState argument of setState's function as mutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I know `this.state` is not supposed to be modified directly, instead `setState` should be used.

From this I inferred that `prevState` should be also treated as immutable and instead `setState` should always look something like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  // Create a new object instance to return
  const state = { ...prevState };
  state.counter = state.counter + 1;
  return state;
});
```

Or with deeper nesting:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  // Create a new object instance to return
  const state = { ...prevState, counter: { ...prevState.counter } };
  state.counter.value = state.counter.value + 1;
  return state;
});
```

Or just a partial update like would be with `setState({})` where easier and nicer to use:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
```

All of the above are obviously correct because they return a new instance, but then I came across [this question where the accepted answer encourages mutating `prevState` without returning a new object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43305429/2715716) (notice the code block in the question).

Something like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  prevState.flag = !prevState.flag;
  return prevState;
});
```

I found this to be a sketchy suggestion so I decided to test if the object instance references of `prevState` and `this.state` are the same:

[(The JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/f4z9wgh4/3)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  onDemonstrateButtonClick = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (prevState === this.state) alert(`uh, yep`);
      prevState.counter++;
      return prevState;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onDemonstrateButtonClick}>Demonstrate</button>
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Whadayaknow, they are! So which is it? Is the answer wrong and should I return a new object instance or return partial update as a new object or can I go wild and mutate the `prevState` argument directly? And if yes, *how is this any different from mutating `this.state` directly*?

Side note: TypeScript React typings do not mark the argument as `ReadOnly` which only adds to my confusion.

Comment: It's the first time I hear that you have to clone **whole** state object before using `setState` function. It's kind of abstraction for me. Anyways - you can't mutate but **their properties** - e.g. if you have an array, you can't use `push` method because it works **in situ** and will mutate. That's why it's suggested to use `spread syntax` or even `concat`. The same with integers. `i++` will mutate, but `i + 1` nope.

Comment: Short answer: don't mutate prevState either.

Comment: @KonradD I have edited my question to drop the word clone because I meant to say "return a new object instance" (whether using spread or push or what have you) all along.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer Summing up - `this.setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));` is fully correct for me. But if anyone more experienced than me could approve it or reject, would appreciate it.

Comment: @KonradD see my other update I clearly wrote this question very awkwardly, not even giving example of what I think is wrong and asking if it is, just giving examples of what I know is right.

Comment: The statement "state should be immutable", is often repeated without reason. State must be immutable if using `PureComponent` because React will do a shallow comparison checking for different object references. If comparing state in `shouldComponentUpdate`, then immutability might help for efficient reference equality checks. Otherwise, feel free to mutate state since React will blindly rerender without checks anyway.

Comment: Don't mutate. The answer you link states _it is going to work_, not that _it should be done_. Notice how he write about a "clearer" alternative right after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### First Point

> Is it okay to treat the prevState argument of setState's function as
>   mutable?

The answer is **NO** you should never mutate `prevState`, this is also clearly mentioned in react [documentation in setState section](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

- > prevState is a reference to the previous state. It should not be
  >   directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a
  >   new object based on the input from prevState and props.

### Second Point:

You tested `prevState` and `this.state` and they are the same, well actually they are not.

To figure out why they are actually different we need to know why `prevState` actually exist, and the answer is that `setState` function is asynchronous, thats why react js is giving us access to `prevState` lets check the example below where `prevState != this.state`

In the example below we will increment counter twice per click, but we will use 2 `setState` operations each one of them will increment the counter by 1.

Because `setState` is `async` you will notice that the second `setState` operation started before the first `setState` is finished this is where `prevState` is useful and here `prevState` and `this.state` are not equal.

I commented each line with a number denoting when this line is executed, this should explain why we need `prevState` and why it is different from `this.state`.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter : 1
    };
  }

  increment = () =>{
    this.setState((prevState , props) => {
      console.log("in first"); //3
      console.log(prevState);  //3
      console.log(this.state); //3
      if(prevState == this.state)
      {
         console.log("in first prevState == this.state");
      }
      return {
        counter : prevState.counter+1
      }
    } , ()=>{
      console.log("done updating first"); //5
    });


    console.log("after first"); //1

    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      console.log("in second"); //4
      console.log(this.state);  //4
      console.log(prevState);   //4
      if (prevState == this.state) {
        console.log("in second prevState == this.state");
      }
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }
    } , () =>{
      console.log("done updating second"); //6
    });

    console.log("after second"); //2

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.counter}</span>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.increment} >increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The Result from the above code is

```
"after first"
"after second"
"in first"
▶Object {counter: 1}
▶Object {counter: 1}
"in first prevState == this.state"
"in second"
▶Object {counter: 1}
▶Object {counter: 2}
"done updating first"
"done updating second"
```

The above code is fully working in this link, you can check the console.log result
https://codesandbox.io/s/k325l485mr

---

The above example will correctly increment counter twice per click, if you want to break it change return statement in second `setState`

from

```
return {
    counter: prevState.counter + 1
}
```

to

```
return {
    counter: this.state.counter + 1
}
```

and you will find that the result is not correct each click will result in 1 increment which is not correct because we have 2 `setState` , this is because we didn't use `prevState` and we used an incorrect `this.state`

### Finally

I believe that the correct way to update the counter is

`this.setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));`

Comment: Thank you for the example where `prevState` doesn't reference the same object as `this.state`. I knew this in abstract, but couldn't put it to code and thanks to you I now feel like I actually understand it. Also apologies for the obvious fail in not checking the documentation, but now I am glad I didn't because I might not ask this question otherwise and this awesome answer wouldn't exist.

Comment: Just FYI the docs have been lightly updated to not refer to `state` in the updater function as `prevState`: "state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated."