# Avoid using callback in setState when referencing the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, setstate

I still get [this error](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md) but I don't understand how it is possible in my code:

```
export default class GenericTable extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      otherStuff: '',
      ...props, // rows are received on props
      sort: {
        col: 0,
        asc: true,
      },
    };
  }

  onSortChange = i => {
    const tempRows = this.state.rows;
    const tempSort = this.state.sort; // this is the line where it says about that error

    const newRows = [];
    if (tempSort.asc) {
      newRows = tempRows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.cells[i] < b.cells[i]) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.cells[i] > b.cells[i]) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    } else {
      newRows = tempRows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.cells[i] > b.cells[i]) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.cells[i] < b.cells[i]) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    tempSort.col = [i];
    tempSort.asc = !tempSort.asc;
    this.setState({ rows: newRows, sort: tempSort });
  };
...
}
```

So, it is where `tempSort` is declared. How should it be changed in order to work?

I don't see the similarity with the described on eslint's page.

Comment: So your tempSort is set with the old state ?

Comment: did you mean to copy the object instead of mutating it in place? `const tempSort = {...this.state.sort}`?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341828/1176601

Comment: @Aprillion, I guess that's the same what Rosen Dimov said to do but does not work

Comment: This question looks very good place to read about the state mutations we've been discussing. Be sure to check it out as it's out of the scope of your question here (and there's no point re-explaining something which was explained well there). ;)

Answer (score 1):

**@Leo Messi**, aren't you supposed to be preparing for the Napoli game on Saturday? :)

Joking aside...

You'll need to use [this form of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) which accepts a function called with the previous state so logic inside the function operates on the same state. In the end it should return the newly computed state.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            otherStuff: '',
            ...props, // rows are received on props
            sort: {
                col: 0,
                asc: true
            }
        };
    }

    getNewState(prevState, i) {
        const tempSort = prevState.sort;
        const tempRows = this.state.rows;
        let newRows = [];

        if (tempSort.asc) {
            newRows = tempRows.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a.cells[i] < b.cells[i]) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.cells[i] > b.cells[i]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        } else {
            newRows = tempRows.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a.cells[i] > b.cells[i]) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.cells[i] < b.cells[i]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        }
        tempSort.col = [i];
        tempSort.asc = !tempSort.asc;
        return { rows: newRows, sort: tempSort };
    }

    onSortChange = i => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return this.getNewState(prevState, i);
        });
    };

    render() {
        return <p>test</p>;
    }
}
```

Tested in on my VS Code with the rule in question added to my `.eslintrc.js`. But nevertheless, keep in mind that putting your state computation logic in the version with the `prevState` param doesn't prevent you from introducing other issues (as I mentioned in my previous version of the answer, not creating new objects, but mutating existing ones, where the first was expected. I removed that part of the answer as it actually doesn't solve that particular issue, but I suggest you check it again in the edit history).

Comment: So basically you say to replace `const tempSort = this.state.sort;` with `const tempSort = {...this.state.sort}; ` - if so, it doesn't work in my case. It stills returns the same error. I also repalced `const tempRows = this.state.rows;` with `const tempRows = [...this.state.rows];` but the error says to be at the line with `tempSort`

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce it in a codesandbox a little later. Or you already have a sandbox which can show the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one but I can paste the whole file here: https://pastebin.com/idWCQkLN

Comment: I updated my answer, it doesn't give me ESLint errors in VS Code anymore, but I haven't tested how the code behaves at runtime, but it should be equivalent I guess. Removed the explanations about state mutation and creating new objects as that actually doesn't solve the issue with ESLint, but I suggest you check them and keep them in mind (they can be seen in the edit history of the answer).

Comment: you are still mutating `prevState` in the pastebin

Comment: I tried your new version. I don't know if it's something with my code but now I have this error: ` Line 23:7:  Unused state field: 'sort'  react/no-unused-state` - it is in state where `sort` is declared

Comment: For the pastebin I provided, that's normal, because I don't use the state at all, I get the warning on line 8 where state is declared. But if I use the state in the view, like ```JSON.stringify(this.state)``` for example, the error goes away. So maybe you have some obsolete code?

Comment: @Aprillion - I explained why I removed my comments about mutating state from my answer. It's a different topic which would make the answer very verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The React [Main Concepts - 5. State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) lists rules to
follow:

> ### Using State Correctly
>
> There are three things you should know about `setState()`.
>
> #### Do Not Modify State Directly
>
> For example, this will not re-render a component:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.state.comment = 'Hello';
> ```
>
> Instead, use `setState()`:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
> ```
>
> The only place where you can assign `this.state` is the constructor.
>
> #### State Updates May Be Asynchronous
>
> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for
> performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously,
> you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> For example, this code may fail to update the counter:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.setState({
>   counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
> });
> ```
>
> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function
> rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state
> as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is
> applied as the second argument:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState((state, props) => ({
>   counter: state.counter + props.increment
> }));
> ```
>
> We used an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) above, but it also works with regular
> functions:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState(function(state, props) {
>   return {
>     counter: state.counter + props.increment
>   };
> });
> ```
>
> #### State Updates are Merged
>
> When you call `setState()`, React merges the object you provide into
> the current state.
>
> For example, your state may contain several independent variables:
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>   super(props);
>   this.state = {
>     posts: [],
>     comments: []
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> Then you can update them independently with separate `setState()`
> calls:
>
> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>   fetchPosts().then(response => {
>     this.setState({
>       posts: response.posts
>     });
>   });
>
>   fetchComments().then(response => {
>     this.setState({
>       comments: response.comments
>     });
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> The merging is shallow, so `this.setState({comments})` leaves
> `this.state.posts` intact, but completely replaces
> `this.state.comments`.

With your provided code snippet you break two of these rules. Let's
first handle the one that causes the JSLint warning:

> Prevent using this.state within a this.setState
> (react/no-access-state-in-setstate)

You get this warning because of:

> State Updates May Be Asynchronous ... Because `this.props` and
> `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on
> their values for calculating the next state.

Both `newRows` and `tempSort` are based upon the previous state. The
JSLint warning is saying that you should use the callback variation of
`setState()`.

```
onSortChange = i => {
  this.setState(({ rows: tempRows, sort: tempSort }) => {
    // sort
    return { rows: newRows, sort: tempSort };
  });
};
```

With the warning handled let's have a look at another issue within the
snippet. `sort()` sorts the elements in-place, meaning that the
original is modified. Similarly `tempSort.col = [i]` and `tempSort.asc = !tempSort.asc` also both modify the current state. **Assigning an
object to a new variable does not create a copy.** Both variables will
simply refer to the same object.

```js
const object_1 = { a: 1 };
const object_2 = object_1;

object_2.a = 2;

console.log("object_1", object_1);
console.log("object_2", object_2);
```

Make sure you copy an object before mutating an object or using
in-place methods.

```
 const tempRows = [...this.state.rows];
 const tempSort = {...this.state.sort};
```

Both create a shallow copy of the array/object before assigning it to
a variable.

With the above being said a solution might look something like this:

```js
/* Comparator factories. sort[true] is ascending, sort[false] is descending.
 * This factory accepts a function that is called for both a and b,
 * comparing their return values.
 *
 *     items.sort(sort[true](item => item.a))
 *
 * Sorts an array of items based on their "a" property in ascending order.
 */
const sort = {
   true: (fn) => (a, b) => (a = fn(a), b = fn(b), -(a < b) || +(a > b)),
  // flip a, b arguments for descending order
  false: (fn) => (a, b) => sort[true](fn)(b, a),
};

class GenericTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ordered: props.data };
  }
    
  handler(i) {
    // use a callback because the new state depends on the old state
    this.setState(({ordered, i: iPrevious, asc}) => {
      asc = i != iPrevious || !asc;
      return { 
        i, asc,
        // copy `ordered` before using the in-place `sort` method
        ordered: [...ordered].sort(sort[asc](row => row[i]))
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>{this.props.headers.map((header, i) => (
            <th key={i} onClick={() => this.handler(i)}>{header}</th>
          ))}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.ordered.map((row, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              {row.map((cell, i) => <td key={i}>{cell}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GenericTable
    headers={["a", "b", "c"]}
    data={[[1, 5, 10], [6, 11, 2], [12, 3, 7]]}
  />,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```css
th{cursor: pointer}th,td{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```